# How to create dynamic id selector in Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My php code goes something like this way-

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
$id='selectThisID-' . $i;
?>
<div id="<?php echo $id;?>">On Select this Div(say #selectThisID-3)<?php echo $field-n; ?></div>

<?php $id= 'paraID-' . $i;
<p id="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display:none">Toggle this para(say #paraID-3) for selected ID only</p>
}
```

Now how can I handle this variable number of id's in my jQuery. As I know for single div statement it could be:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("[id^=selectThisID-]").click(function(){
                $("[id^=paraID-]").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

So on selecting element with id `'#selectThisID-1'`, `<p>` will toggle. How can I use `#selectThisID-2, #selectThisID-3....#selectThisID-n` as jQuery selector. How can I get value of 'n' from php code to jQuery? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Suppose `$n=5`, so there are total 5 `div` elements. Now the problem is that when I select any of `div`(say `#selectThisID-3`) all `<p>` elements get toggled(i.e.

with `#paraID-1, #paraID-2....#paraID-5` all toggled). However I need to toggle para-3 when div-3 selected, toggle para-4 when div-4 selected and so on. Please help.

Comment: much simpler just adding a common class instead of using ID

Answer (score 4):

```
$("[id^=selectThisID-]").click(function(){
    $("#paraID-"+this.id.split('-')[1]).toggle();
});
```

Comment: will toggle every paragraph on page

Comment: @charlietfl yea. he'd actually edited it sometime after I'd answered, so I didn't notice the location of the P. above should work now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ID use class. This is more efficient then what you have there.
For example:

```
$(".your-class").each(function(index, domEl){
              $(this).val();
              $(this).toggle();
        });
```

Comment: He wants to use IDs. Maybe he has a reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using class on elements and `index()` method to match them with no ID's involved:

```
var $divGroup=$('.divClass').click(function(){
    var index=$divGroup.index(this);
    $('.paragraphClass').hide().eq( index).show();
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UZqD3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an id, use a class and put the corresponding `p` `id` in a custom attribute:

```
$(".selectThisID").click(function(){
    $("paraID-" + this.getAttribute("data-target")).toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="selectThisID" data-target="5">foo</div>
<p id="paraID-5">bar</p>
```